# Ansible Ad-hoc commands requests vault passwords

Tags: ansible

This afternoon when running ansible ad-hoc commands I've started to be prompted for the vault passwords.

The process shouldn't need this and this was never required before.

I'm just running something like

```
ansible prod_servers -m shell -a "ls -al /var/logs/" --sudo
```

I can just provide the password and the command works, but it's driving me crazy.

We're using ansible 1.8.4 (don't ask) :(

Comment: Do you have an `ansible.cfg` file in the directory where you run your ansible command? If so make sure ask_vault_pass is set to False.

Comment: @tehmoon No change unfortunately.

Comment: try setting `--vault-password-file /dev/null`.  Not 100% sure it'll work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was no change **this afternoon** on other systems and the question does not contain other information.

Comment: @techraf that's why I am asking the question though. If I had made a change that resulted in this effect I would just reverse it. Obviously something has changed, I was hoping it was something someone had come across before.

Comment: But SO's purpose is not solving mysteries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for vaulted files under `group_vars`/`host_vars` in your inventory – this should be the only reason why password prompt may appear for ad-hoc commands.

Comment: Both the host_vars and group_vars folders have several vault files, holding passwords at the relevant levels, but these have always been there and didn't used to require decrypting to run an ad-hoc command.

Comment: May be you had `ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE` set in your environment and was unaware of transparent decryption process?

Comment: Actually, this has lead me to the answer, or at least the problem.
We'd moved some playbooks into subfolders, which then didn't work with the inventories file being in a sub-folder. Moving the inventory file back to a sub-folder stops the ansible ad-hoc command requiring decryption of the vaults. Now I just have to figure out if I can stop it, but at least I have the real problem.